# To read from distributed cache or from HDFS output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-caching

I'm implementing an iterative algorithm that produces some result in each iteration and that result is used in the map phase of the next iteration.

Should I make that result available for Mapper using distributed cache, or should I just read it from HDFS? What is more efficient?

That file should not be that big. The idea is just to read it in the setup phase and keep it in memory of mapper.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file isn't that big and will be read in the setup of the mapper, DistributedCache is the way forward. Of course if you're not reading anything else into that second job, it begs the question as to why you're using a MapReduce job.

Reading from the HDFS (i.e. streaming a file into a mapper through an InputFormat) and using the DistributedCache have two quite different use cases. DistributedCache is designed for small files which can fit in memory, whereas reading into a mapper using an InputFormat is designed for large distributed datasets that can only be processed using a distributed process.

If your dataset is small enough for use in a DistributedCache, you can just use a Java job to process it and avoid the large overheads of MapReduce.

Comment: The data read in setup is used in mapper for each record, that's why I need it. But that data also changes after each iteration, so after each iteration I would need to put that data to distributed cache and then read it from the mapper of the next job. Does your advice still count? To be more concrete, there are two jobs. For example, first job generates some number through map-reduce. Second job needs to read that number in setup and divide all records by that number. I'm oversimplifying, but you get the idea. So distributed cache still, or reading from output?

Comment: Ah OK, so you have some large data set being read into the second job as well as the small output from the first job. It might be worth making that more explicit in your question. The answer is still DistributedCache, unless you're running the interations from one single driver class, in which case you can simply add the one number you generate in the first job into the Configuration object, and then simply call that in the second job.

Comment: Yes, you are correct,I should have been more explicit in my question.I am running iterations from a single driver, but I cannot put the result from first job into Configuration, cause it's not that small, it's not a number, but a collection of at most 100-1000 arrays, while each has 400 elements(so a couple of MBs).I also think that it is better solution to use Distributed cache in case of small files,but I'm not sure because that's not the same file through iterations, so I have to put it into Distributed cache after first job in iteration. This is a better solution than to read it from HDFS?